# Android App for Continuous Image Capture

Tags: android, images

I am looking for an Android app that captures images continuously and saves them as separate uncompressed image files (PNG). I don't want any lossy compression because I need the exact images as stored in a RAM buffer.

Note that I am not after a app to extract still images from a video file.